# MeteorJs runs really slow in client

Tags: meteor, performance

just installed MeteorJs in my llaptop, os Debian, newest Meteor.

As i use meteor on my llaptop it works great but when i try to open the app from my desktop computer(it is in the same lan network) it takes about 10-12 minutes to load the basic app that is installed when you type meteor create app.

Is there something I should do or know. I tried to remove autopublish though.

Best regards,
Emi

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't trust a Developer mode when testing your Meteor app. It depends on a few reasons and as in common - your app works fine in Production